# Continue editing datagrid row even if row has error validation rule

Tags: wpf, datagrid, validationrule

I put some ValidationRule on my datagrid, validation rule works fine but if I have an error on row, I can't edit an other row or other cell.

I want to allow users to enter bad value and fix it after. 
Could I do this with wpf validation rule?

Comment: Of cause it can be done. Imagine INotifyDataErrorInfo is nothing but ErrorsChanged event, it's up to other part of your program decide what to do when the ErrorsChanged event triggered. My best guess is that some part of your datagrid implement some sort of OnLostFocus event and set the focus back to itself when validation fail.

Comment: Can I override Error datagrid behavior?